# Is it Item based or content based Collaborative filtering?

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

(Updated code)
Hi all i want to filtering items for count and quality using the filter functionality in meanjs app. then i tried many ways but unable to get the solution if any one knows the solution please help me.....

here is my [plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZCxNLBPWvhnXrTYisW5?p=preview)

Count All

```
 <div class="col-md-2 form-group form-group-default"> 
           <label>Quality</label> <select data-ng-model="searchtable.quality" id="quality" ng-options="item.quantity as item.quantity for item in descriptionyarnqualitys" class="form-control" placeholder="Quality"required><option value="">All</option></select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a working Plunker, load all the required libraries and provide mocks for your services... So what is `Descriptionyarnqualitys.query()` returning?

Comment: my code updated please check and help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quality property is a sub property of colorshades and not of the order itself. Use `searchtable.colorshades.quality` model name and it [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/z8268J90nvVpJd3CTCTy?p=preview)

dynamically extract the 'quality' value from the order list:

```
$scope.getDescriptionyarnqualitys = function() {
  var qualities = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.sryarnorders, function(order) {
    angular.forEach(order.colorshades, function(shade) {
      qualities[shade.quality]=shade.quality;
    });
  }) 
  return qualities;
};
```

In the HTML you can call the function to extract the available qualities:

```
<select data-ng-model="searchtable.colorshades.quality" id="quality" ng-options="name for (name, value) in getDescriptionyarnqualitys()" class="form-control" placeholder="Quality" required>
```

Hope this help.